# Pandas calling apply on an empty dataframe using the reduce option changes datatypes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I understand that apply method is called even for the empty dataframe. When there is error inside the apply method it doesn't get propagated. I was looking at this stackoverflow link which suggests to use the `reduce` option so that the apply function is not called. 
[Pandas: why does DataFrame.apply(f, axis=1) call f when the DataFrame is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21225552/pandas-why-does-dataframe-applyf-axis-1-call-f-when-the-dataframe-is-empty)

Consider this example, in Col1, everything is less than 10. So the dataframe is empty. when I use the reduce option, the datatype of col2 is changed. It converts the numbers to decimals.

```
    d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
    mask = df["col1"] > 10
    df.loc[mask, "col2"] = df[mask].apply(lambda x: x+2, axis=1, result_type='reduce')
    print(df)
```

Expected output

```
      col1    col2
   0    1       3
   1    2       4
```

Actual output:

```
      col1    col2
   0    1      3.0
   1    2      4.0
```

I am not sure why it converts the integers to decimals. Does anyone know how to avoid this?

Comment: To avoid float conversion, use `df[mask].apply(lambda x: x+2, axis=1, result_type='reduce').astype(int)` To understand why float occurs, do `axis=0`, you will see the introduction of `NaN` which has type `float64`. In similar fashion, when you do `axis=1`, we have no rows in output but type has been converted to `float64`

Comment: Simply `df.loc[mask, "col2"] = df[mask].apply(lambda x: x+2, axis=1, result_type='reduce').astype(int)`  should do the Job

Comment: Thank you @meW for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pd.to_numeric()` for downcasting to integer.

> I will update this if I find something better to do this.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
>>> mask = df["col1"] > 10
>>> df.loc[mask, "col2"] = df[mask].apply(lambda x: x+2, axis=1, result_type='reduce')
>>>
>>> df
   col1  col2
0     1   3.0
1     2   4.0
>>>
>>> pd.to_numeric(df.col2, downcast='integer')
0    3
1    4
Name: col2, dtype: int8
>>>
>>> df.col2 = pd.to_numeric(df.col2, downcast='integer')
>>> df
   col1  col2
0     1     3
1     2     4
>>>
```